# Form displayed in wrong size Delphi xe7 iOS

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I uploaded a project built with an older version of delphi into Delphi XE7 and this is the result when deploying to iPhone Simulator 5. [image]

How can I fix so that the black space is gone and the form is sized/displayed correctly?

UPDATE:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 640
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop, iPhone, iPad]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object Text1: TText
    Position.X = 200.000000000000000000
    Position.Y = 128.000000000000000000
    Text = 'test'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide us the data of the `.fmx` file?

Comment: Is that just down to the simulated device having a resolution that doesn't fill the simulator window?

Comment: Indeed, actually this looks like an issue with the simulator, given the toolbar is also below the black region.

Comment: Well... This is only happening to this specific project. That form is a new form I added within the project. Any other project looks as they should within the same simulator.

Comment: Have you created a view for that particular device? If so, try removing that particular device view (will also erase any customization done to that view and restore back to the master view).

Comment: I am just using the 'Master' view? One of the forms previously made in an older version of Delphi does have views created for it. I've tried removing them all from the project root but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I usually do all my work on the master view and never use the device views until I'm getting ready to deploy the app (each view adds a heavy load to the IDE).

Comment: Note: the other form previously mentioned does not have a view created for iPhone 5.

Comment: Did you click the button in the IDE to delete the views? Or did you just delete the files and let the IDE break when it cannot find the files?

Comment: Are you sure you in the project manager have chosen to deploy to target "iPhone 5" and not just "iPhone"? It looks like the simulator runs it as an iPhone 4 (and previous) application, which the "iPhone" target corresponds to.